# how to copy the value of a cell to another cell by searching a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here's what I mean:
How do I create a formula that will find and copy the first cell in the column that is a negative number?
I know this isn't correct, but it's where I'm starting.
=if(E:E,<0,?)

I've been searching for answers to this question, but I hardly even know how to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first number less than 0 in column E:

```
=INDEX(E:E,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E)))/($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1E+99,E:E))<0),1))
```